# Setup Rancher to manage my Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I Want to setup Rancher to manage my Kubernetes Cluster.
I installed rancher on the Ubuntu and when try to connect I got the error.

Steps that I ran:

```
curl --insecure -sfL https://localhost/v3/import/zkzmqg5kjpcqmw9qplrskzwwvwhgbbzdk2z9dn579rhpp66wt65wgj.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

I got this error:

```
curl --insecure -sfL https://localhost/v3/import/zkzmqg5kjpcqmw9qplrskzwwvwhgbbzdk2z9dn579rhpp66wt65wgj.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

Any idea how I can To fix the problem?

Comment: There is an option to use the hostname instead of localjost to identify Rancher. Can you try it? Are you running `curl` on the same machine as Rancher?

Comment: Bruno, Can you send the example please?